# What is the name of this tool? It almost looks like an Allen without the wrench

Tags: tools

[image: hexigon shaped type thing]
[image: hexigon shaped type thing]

Any body have any idea what this thing is called?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is just an Allen *driver bit* - you use it with a detachable head screwdriver.

Comment: I've also heard it called a hex bit.

Comment: Yup. It just happens to be the 1/4" one, which is the standard bit shank size.